# Unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference error in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iscroll

My script:

```
var slidespeed = 200;
$('.noti_user a').off().on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.sub_menu_closer').hide();
        $('.noti_drop_down').slideUp(slidespeed);
    }else{
        $('.left_user_inner').children('div').children('a').removeClass('active');
        $('.left_logo_part a').removeClass('active')
        $('.help_drop_down,.mail_drop_down').slideUp(slidespeed)
        $('.logo_drop_down').slideUp(slidespeed);
        $('.noti_drop_down').slideDown(slidespeed,function(){
            sScroll.refresh(); // here is error show
        });
        $('.sub_menu_closer').show();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
})

var sScroll; // here iscroll call
   sScroll = new IScroll('.noti_outer', {scrollbars: 'custom',mouseWheel: true});
   document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

`sScroll.refresh();` here is i refresh iScroll plugin

when i testing in ie8 browser this show error : Unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Post the line(s) where you set sScroll. This is missing.

Comment: @axel.michel added line of sScroll

Comment: Are you sure that IScroll compatible with ie8? As far as I know IScroll was born to fill a hole in mobile browsers support for overflow:scroll and has no support for older desktop browsers.

Comment: i know that it is not supported in old browsers but error is show of refresh property @axel.michel

Comment: Since it is not supported how should sScroll have a method "refresh"?

Comment: than i have to refresh that sScroll in that function because other wise sScroll not working in any browsers is there any other way ? @axel.michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above. The IScroll lib is not compatible with older IE versions. Therefore you can't call a method. To prevent the error, you can go like this:

```
  $('.noti_drop_down').slideDown(slidespeed,function(){
    if (sScroll && typeof sScroll === 'object' && typeof sScroll.refresh === 'function') {
     sScroll.refresh(); // here is error show
    }
  });
```

This might be to many conditions in the if statement, simply check what sScroll is in IE, if it is undefined, reduce the conditions, but it should avoid the error.

Comment: no sorry it is not working. slideDown my dropdown is not working with this condition my dropdown stopped working

Comment: in this case you have to put the if condition inside the the slidedown method, see modified answer.